# TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable

Tags: python, for-loop, typeerror

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dna.py", line 63, in <module>
    main()
  File "dna.py", line 35, in main
    repeats[strings] = countRepeats(strings, sequence_copy)
  File "dna.py", line 55, in countRepeats
    while (strings)*(i+1) in sequence:
TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable
```

```
import csv
from sys import *



#psuedocode:
#open files
#get the dna strings that we are looking for 
#loop through the .txt file. if the string is repeated, return the number of times 
#compare the number of times repeated with csvfile and comapre people
def main():
    if len(argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")
        exit(1)

    # open the two files from command line
    database = open(argv[1], 'r')
    sequence = open(argv[2],'r')
    
    # make the database into a dictionary which contains the strings we want
    db_file = csv.DictReader(database)
    #loads the strings we are comparing
    strs = db_file.fieldnames[1:]
    
    # put the sequence in a file we can read
    sequence_copy = sequence.read
    sequence.close
            
    #create a dictionary where we have the sequence and the amount of times it showes up
    repeats = {}
    for strings in strs:
        # will make the keys the dna strings we are looking for and will give them values of the most repeats
        repeats[strings] = countRepeats(strings, sequence_copy)
    
    for row in database:
        if match(strs, repeats, row):
            print(f"{row['name']}")
            database.close
        else:
            print("No match")
            database.close

def match(strs, repeats, row):
    # dna_seqence is the dictionary we make to hold hte repeat counts found
    for str in strs:
        if repeats != int(row[str]):
            return False
        return True

def countRepeats(strings, sequence):
    counter = 0
    # "ATCT" if found looks for => "ATCTATCT" and so on. 
    while strings*(counter+1) in sequence:
        counter += 1
    return counter
    

            
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

countRepeats goes through a .txt file and gets the largest number of repeats of a string. For simplicity's sake, it's just a number. I want to use `for strings in strs:` loop to go through this dictionary, make new keys and give them values.

strs is a dictionary with items that are the strings that I want to check for rrepeats. Form the csvfile, they look as such:
[image: what strs are]

This is what a sequence looks like:
[image: it is a one line string of nucleotides]

Am I not allowed to iterate like this? How do I properly iterate?

Comment: What is `strs`? The code you have shared seems to be incomplete and is currently invalid Python syntax (indentation problems). Please update your question to include a [mre]

Comment: Can you post a simplified version of the script that would work for us with copy/paste. The fragment you've posted doesn't show what `sequence` is, It comes from the caller's `sequence_copy`,... but what's that? Find out what the paramters to `countRepeats(strings, sequence_copy)` are, then that is what forms your test scirpt.

Comment: of course, my bad.